# Multiple nested AJAX requests with arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I'm using Axios / promises to make AJAX requests, but the structure is a bit confusing. Basically I want this to happen:

1. Get `masterlist.xml`.
2. Parse the master list to get an array of category list URLs.
3. Get each `category.xml`.
4. Parse each category list to get an array of manifest URLs.
5. Get each `manifest.xml` and parse data.

Example structure:

**masterlist.xml**

```
<master>
  <category>action</category>
  <category>romance</category>
</master>
```

**Category XMLs (e.g. action.xml and romance.xml)**

```
<manifestUrls>
  <manifest>foo/bar/manifest.xml</manifest>
  <manifest>alice/bob/manifest.xml</manifest>
  <manifest>hello/world/manifest.xml</manifest>
</manifestUrls>
```

**Manifest XMLs**

```
<manifest>
  <data>Blah blah blah</data>
<manifest>
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to structure this as an Axios request with `then`. I'd like to have three functions, `getMaster()`, `getCategory(url)`, and `getManifest(url)` that are preferably independent (e.g. `getMaster` doesn't have to call `getCategory` directly), but it seems like it might be necessary.

How would this be structured in Axios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main benefits of promises is that they allow you to easily avoid interdependence between your methods.

Here is a rough outline of how you could do this.

```
// put it all together
getMaster()
    .then(parseMaster)
    .then(function (categories) {
        return Promise.all(categories.map(getAndParseCategory));
    })
    .then(flatten)  // the previous then() resolves to an array-of-arrays
    .then(function (manifestUrls) {
        return Promise.all(manifestUrls.map(getManifest));
    })
    .then(function (manifests) {
        // manifests is an array of all manifests
    });


// Examples of what each of the functions used above would do
function getMaster() {
    return axios.get('masterUrl')
        .then(function (response) { return response.data; });
}

function parseMaster(masterContent) {
    // parse and return an array of categories
}

function getCategory(name) {
    var url = // ... build the URL based on the name

    return axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) { return response.data; });
}

function parseCategory(categoryContent) {
    // parse and return an array of URLs synchronously for one category
}

function getAndParseCategory(name) {
    return getCategory(name).then(parseCategory);
}

function getManifest(url) {
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) { return response.data; });
}

function flatten(arrayOfArrays) {
    return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
}
```

If you're using Bluebird or something else that gives promises a `.map()` method, then you can tidy that pipeline up a bit:

```
// using Promise.resolve() at the beginning to ensure 
// the chain is based of the desired kind of promise
Promise.resolve()
    .then(getMaster)
    .then(parseMaster)
    .map(getCategory)
    .map(parseCategory)
    .then(flatten)       // previous line resolves to an array-of-arrays
    .map(getManifest)
    .then(function (manifests) {
        // manifests is an array of all manifests
    });
```

Of course, you could also define your own `.map` method if you don't want to import a whole third party promise library:

```
if (!Promise.prototype.map) {
    Promise.prototype.map = function (func) {
        return this.then(function (result) {
            return Promise.all(result.map(func));
        });
    };
}
```

**Edit:** To respond to your question in the comments below. If you wanted to pass the category text along so that it could be included in the manifest URLs, I think a clean way to do this would be to include that in the data returned from `getCategory()` so that `parseCategory` can make use of it. Everything else could stay the same.

Example:

```
function getCategory(name) {
    var url = // ... build the URL based on the name

    return axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) { 
            return {
                name: name,
                data: response.data 
            };
        });
}

function parseCategory(categoryContent) {
    var urls = // parse URLs from categoryContent.data

    return urls.map(function (url) {
        return categoryContent.name + '/' + url;
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks super clean and readable. I do have a follow up question, though - what if I wanted to combine previous `then` results, such as constructing a manifest URL like `action/alice/bob/manifest.xml` or `action/foo/bar/manifest.xml`? What would need to change?

Comment: @user341554 Added one possible solution to the end of my answer.